# Applied for ESTA and was denied. Subsequently, secured a visa and travelled to US. Can I try ESTA again?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, esta, australian-citizens

I was rejected for a visitor visa for the USA when I was an Indian citizen. Now I am an Australian Citizen.  I applied for ESTA, which got denied, maybe due to my previous rejection. Since then I have travelled to the USA 4 times with valid visa. My visa will expire in 2020.  Should I renew my Visa again, or should I try applying for ESTA?  My visa has been renewed 2 times already.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE!  I have attempted to correct the grammar of your question.  Please feel free to edit it further (using the "edit" link" below the tags) if I have changed your meaning in any way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My ESTA approval if I have previously had a B1 refusal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26431/my-esta-approval-if-i-have-previously-had-a-b1-refusal) or [Will I be granted ESTA after getting rejected thrice on different nationality?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138992/will-i-be-granted-esta-after-getting-rejected-thrice-on-different-nationality)

Comment: I don't think this can be labeled a duplicate. Either way, I suggest you get a solid answer from your local US consulate.

Comment: @Ozzy I'm with Ozzy. I don't think this is a duplicate. Nominating to reopen.

Comment: @Ozzy it's a near-exact duplicate of the first question, and the answer that comes with it gives the most detailed answer applicable here.

Comment: @jcaron I don't see how it's a duplicate - in this question, OP has been successfully granted a visa

Comment: @JoeMalt the question includes "If not and I need to apply for visa is it every time I need to travel to stated or is it just the first time?", which is the same as this one, and the answer explains that you need to continue to answer you have had a rejection, and that even though it probably makes it unlikely the ESTA will get approved, it is not a certainty, which is basically the same as the answer below...

Answer (score 3):

You’re eligible to apply:

> **Who You Are:**
>
> •   You are a citizen or eligible national of a Visa Waiver Program country.
>
> •   You are currently not in possession of a visitor's visa.
>
> •   Your travel is for 90 days or less.
>
> •   You plan to travel to the United States for business or pleasure.
>
> •   You want to apply for a new authorization for one person or a group of applications for two or more persons.
>
> **What You Need:**
>
> •   Valid passport from a Visa Waiver Program country.
>
> •   Valid credit card (MasterCard, VISA, American Express, and Discover (JCB, Diners Club)) or PayPal to pay the US $14 per application.
>
> •   Your contact information.
>
> •   Your most recent employment information, if applicable.

Source: [ESTA Requirements](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/application.html?execution=e1s1)

Eligibility for an ESTA doesn’t require a clear admission record. Now you of course have to honestly answer the question about whether you’ve ever had a visa denied. But given that you’ve had successive B visas, perhaps your ESTA application will be successful.

Let us know!